# Android Jni: Fastest way to pass a Map from Java to C++?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

The project I'm working on has a map in its Java parts, sometimes, this map is used by its c++ part, the strategy now is to encode the map into Json string and pass it to c++, then decode it. But the map grows as the application running, making the encoding and decoding cost more and more time, is there any faster way to pass an entire map from Java to c++?

The Java map originally is a JSON object, which means there is only string, number, array and map in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to pass down the Java map to C and have it make JNI calls to Java to access the object.  Another would be to do the reverse-  pass the original string to C and parse it there (which ought to be faster) and access it in Java via JNI.  Neither should have a significant time penalty, so long as for the first method you cache the method id and class object of the Java map.